# In Gladman's AES-CTR implementation, what is the if(b_pos) code section for?

Tags: cryptography, aes

Trying to understand Dr Brian Gladman's AES-CTR implementation. (http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/AES/aes-src-12-09-11.zip aes_modes.c line 849 onwards)
I read up on the CTR algorithm, but this implementation mystifies me. *I am unable to see how it matches with the CTR mode algorithm.*

What is the if(b_pos) code section for?

Also I do not understand the conditional 
b_pos < AES_BLOCK_SIZE && len

Since (AES_BLOCK_SIZE && len) will always be 1 while len > 0. AES_BLOCK_SIZE is 16.

```
    if(b_pos)
    {
        memcpy(buf, cbuf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
        if(aes_ecb_encrypt(buf, buf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ctx) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        while(b_pos < AES_BLOCK_SIZE && len)
        {
            *obuf++ = *ibuf++ ^ buf[b_pos++];
            --len;
        }

        if(len)
            ctr_inc(cbuf), b_pos = 0;
    }





AES_RETURN aes_ctr_crypt(const unsigned char *ibuf, unsigned char *obuf,
            int len, unsigned char *cbuf, cbuf_inc ctr_inc, aes_encrypt_ctx ctx[1])
{   unsigned char   *ip;
    int             i, blen, b_pos = (int)(ctx->inf.b[2]);
    uint_8t buf[BFR_LENGTH];
    if(b_pos)
    {
        memcpy(buf, cbuf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
        if(aes_ecb_encrypt(buf, buf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ctx) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        while(b_pos < AES_BLOCK_SIZE && len)
        {
            *obuf++ = *ibuf++ ^ buf[b_pos++];
            --len;
        }

        if(len)
            ctr_inc(cbuf), b_pos = 0;
    }
    while(len)
    {
        blen = (len > BFR_LENGTH ? BFR_LENGTH : len), len -= blen;

        for(i = 0, ip = buf; i < (blen >> 4); ++i)
        {
            memcpy(ip, cbuf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
            ctr_inc(cbuf);
            ip += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        }

        if(blen & (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 1))
            memcpy(ip, cbuf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE), i++;

        if(aes_ecb_encrypt(buf, buf, i * AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ctx) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        i = 0; ip = buf;
            while(i + AES_BLOCK_SIZE <= blen)
            {
                obuf[ 0] = ibuf[ 0] ^ ip[ 0]; obuf[ 1] = ibuf[ 1] ^ ip[ 1];
                obuf[ 2] = ibuf[ 2] ^ ip[ 2]; obuf[ 3] = ibuf[ 3] ^ ip[ 3];
                obuf[ 4] = ibuf[ 4] ^ ip[ 4]; obuf[ 5] = ibuf[ 5] ^ ip[ 5];
                obuf[ 6] = ibuf[ 6] ^ ip[ 6]; obuf[ 7] = ibuf[ 7] ^ ip[ 7];
                obuf[ 8] = ibuf[ 8] ^ ip[ 8]; obuf[ 9] = ibuf[ 9] ^ ip[ 9];
                obuf[10] = ibuf[10] ^ ip[10]; obuf[11] = ibuf[11] ^ ip[11];
                obuf[12] = ibuf[12] ^ ip[12]; obuf[13] = ibuf[13] ^ ip[13];
                obuf[14] = ibuf[14] ^ ip[14]; obuf[15] = ibuf[15] ^ ip[15];
                i += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
                ip += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
                ibuf += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
                obuf += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
            }

        while(i++ < blen)
            *obuf++ = *ibuf++ ^ ip[b_pos++];
    }
    ctx->inf.b[2] = (uint_8t)b_pos;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTR mode makes AES to work like a stream cipher. When encrypting and decrypting, there is no constraint on the data length, especially with respect to block alignment (as it happens with other modes, like CBC).

The function `aes_ctr_crypt()` can be indeed invoked with input data (`ibuf`) of any length.

The problem is that for every invocation, the function needs to remember two things from the previous time:

1. The value of the current *counter block* (which is the parameter `cbuf`)
2. How many bytes it has consumed so far in the current *counter block* (which is information kept in the parameter `ctx` and copied into the local variable `b_pos`).

`b_pos` is therefore the position in the key stream modulo 16.

In other words, when the function completes encryption of a certain piece of data without consuming all 16 bytes in the last *counter block*, it leaves `b_pos` with a value `0<b_pos<16` so that the function can continue from there at the next invocation. A value of `0` means that all bytes in the previous *counter block* have been used up, and that it's time to call the counter function.

Regarding `b_pos < AES_BLOCK_SIZE && len` you should read it as:

```
(b_pos < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) && len
```

Because of operator precedence. The loop terminates either because you run out of "left over" key stream bytes (left hand) or because you run out of cleartext data (right hand).

Comment: excellent explanation! Where is the counter initialized? The IV is supposed to be sent to the receiver so they can use it to decrypt the message. As I understand it, it is usually sent over with the ciphertext. How would this be sent here?

Comment: I think it's up to your application to allocate an initialize the first counter block. It typically contains a random nonce (which your application must somehow send to the receiver) and a initial counter (typically 0). Check out NIST 800-38A for full details.

Comment: I have [link] (http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ctr/ctr-spec.pdf)

Comment: when you say 'key stream' bytes, are you referring to the key? It is unclear to me because once the counter is encrypted with the key, the key is not used again for that counter value.

Comment: For stream ciphers, *keystream* is the data you XOR with the plaintext (while encrypting) or ciphertext (while decrypting). For CTR mode, every time you encrypt the counter you get the next 16 bytes of the keystream. Put differently, when you encrypt data which is N bytes long, you use an N bytes long keystream.

Comment: But since we are in the middle of the keystream, the rest of the AES_BLOCK_SIZE-b_pos counter block bytes are already encrypted. So why are we doing this, effectively discarding the remaining bytes of the keystream? `memcpy(buf, cbuf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
        if(aes_ecb_encrypt(buf, buf, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ctx) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;`

Comment: I guess it simply was an implementation choice. The code is not efficient when you use it to encrypt a byte at a time (because you do 16 times the amount of AES block encryptions than what is really necessary). However, it is still valid CTR mode.

Comment: Not about inefficiency, but about correctness. Shouldn't it be thus? `if(b_pos == 0) {copy counter block into buffer. encrypt buffer} else {XOR the rest of the keystream with the input. if input is left, increment counter.}`

Comment: I also see two other problems, unless I am mistaken. A) From the 800-38a document: B.2 page 19. total number of plaintext blocks <= 2**m where m is number of bits for the counter. There is no such check happening. B) 6.5 page 15. The leftover keystream must be discarded. Yet it is trying to reuse it. If it is saved between invocations as you said, Then the counter cannot be regenerated to decrypt unrelated messages. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @Anil the keystream is indeed discarded at the end of every invocation. The state contains a) AES key b) current counter block and c) number of keystream bytes consumed in the current counter block (that is, b_pos). That allows you to regenerate the keystream of the last block. You are right about the check 2**m; it is typically ignored because m is chosen so that 2**m is much, much larger than the amount of data one plans to encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: yes, per my comment #7,  'the keystream is indeed discarded at the end of every invocation', but then why is the position of the keystream saved between invocations?  "That allows you to regenerate the keystream of the last block.". Suppose Message0 is ciphered and left over keystream is 1230. Next you have Message1. Why is it necessary to save the keystream position to use on this brand new message? It also means that the user must send 1230 to the receiver as the counter for Message1.

Comment: Message0 and Message1 are different chunks of the same big message. CTR allows to split your big message in as many chunk as you want, and of any size. Transmitter and receiver do not need to agree on those and do not need to exchange the position, provided the chunks are not re-ordered. If the last byte of one chunk was in the middle of a counter block (e.g. b_pos==8), the first byte of the next chunk to process must be XOR-ed with the keystream byte at position b_pos==9.

Comment: That clarification helps - I thought Message0 and Message1 are different messages. Thanks!